# Brute Force primality check for 16 bit long integer

Tags: brute-force, primality-test

How can i use the brute force (naive algorithm) to check if a 16 bit long integer is prime or not and print all the prime numbers before it. number example: 1254786951475276. This is my code:

```
   import java.io.*;

public class PrimeNumbers {

    public static boolean checkPrime(long n)
    {
        if (n % 2 == 0)
            return false;

        for (int i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i += 2) 
        {
            if (n % i == 0)
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static void generatePrimeNumbers(long n) {

        for (int i = 2; i<= n-1 ; i++) {

            if (checkPrime(i)) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        long n = 0;
        n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        generatePrimeNumbers(n);
    }
    }
```

Comment: I guess you mean 16 digit....

Comment: Can you describe what you are actually trying to do?  What you've written is a bit of an XY problem, meaning you had one problem and you're asking about another problem which you thought was related but wasn't.  I can tell you that there are 279,238,341,033,925 primes with 16 digits.  If you printed a million every second, it'd still take you nearly 9 years to print the results from this program.  And I can guarantee you such a brute force algorithm won't get remotely close to that speed.

Comment: So you should probably explain what you were trying to do which led you to believing you needed to use this algorithm.  Then it may be easier to suggest better algorithms.

Comment: first i want the user to enter a number upto 16 digits, and that number will be checked if it is prime or not. now the problem with this program which i have written is that it is not accepting 16 digit numbers. How can i perform primality check on a 16 digit number using this program?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean 16 digit, not 16 bit. 16 bit is really easy and you can just check it by a simple loop and division. Your `checkPrime()` can be optimized like this:

```
public static boolean checkPrime(long n)
{
    if (n == 2)
        return true;

    if (n % 2 == 0)
        return false;

    for (long i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i += 2) 
    {
        if (n % i == 0)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

But if number gets too big(I think even for 16 digit, it will not be necessary), you can use [Miller-robin primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test). This test can be used to check if a **VERY BIG** number is prime or not.

If you need to **generate all prime numbers till a specific number**, you can use [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Just remember that `int` range is `-2,147,483,648` to `2,147,483,647`, so it cannot keep 16 digit number. You can use `long` because its range is `-9,223,372,036,854,775,808` to `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`, so it can hold 16 digit number.

Comment: Even after optimization my program is not accepting any number more than 10 digits. I want the program to be able to work with 16 digits maximum. (0-16 digits).

Comment: i tried implementing miller robin primality test, but the program was too complex for me to implement since i am a new programmer. i could not get miller robin test working, So i thought i would just stick to this program and try to get it work.

Comment: @Learner because you are using `int` as input parameter. change your data type to `long`.

Comment: i tried that as well. I still get an error. Did u try running the code after changing the int to long? did it work for u?

Comment: @Learner It should work if you change everything to `long`.